Definitions of modules has a filtration
Recently when I was reading an article, in a proof of Lemma, the author used the definition of a module has a filtration with the  associated graded factors.
Briefly, he considers a restriction of a module $V$ to a subalgebra, denote this subalgebra as $A\otimes B$. Then he says the restriction of $V$ to $A$ has  filtration with the  associated graded factors $V_k\otimes W_k$ where $V_k$ is a $A-$module and $W_k$ is a $B-$module.
My question is how to properly understand this filtrations with given associated graded factors $V_k\otimes W_k$?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

The formulation is hard to comprehend for me. Could you provide the reference?

@MPos  It comes from the Lemma $3.4$ of the paper Combinatorics of q-characters of finite-dimensional representations of quantum affine algebras. Maybe this will take some time to understand the symbols. Thank you.
